# How to sort a List<dynamic> containing ExpandoObjects

Tags: expandoobject

I have a list which contains a dictionary of ExpandoObjects.  Im binding this to a grid but now I want to sort the list.

```
        var rows = new List<dynamic>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            dynamic expandy = new ExpandoObject();
            var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)expandy;

            dictionary.Add("ID", i);
            dictionary.Add("Name", "Name" + i);
            rows.Add(dictionary);
        }
```

So looking at the test code above how would I sort rows (ascending or decending) say on "ID" or "Name" or any other property that I dynamically add?

A bit more info, I'm looking to sort it like this (this doesnt work);

```
            var newOrder = from r in rows
                     orderby ("Name") ascending 
                     select r;
```

Comment: Why make it dynamic if your always putting a Dictionary in it?

Comment: Assuming I change it to var rows = new  List<IDictionary<string, object>> how would i sort it?

Comment: How do you want it sort? Which value in the Dictionary do you want to use?

Comment: Sort it ascending or decending.  On any property in the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this but anyway this works,

```
var newOrder = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x["Name"]);
```

Answer (score 5):

WooHoo's answer does not work for `Dynamic.ExpandoObject`; this works:

```
var newOrder = rows.OrderByDescending(x =>((IDictionary<string,object>)x)["Name"]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This does not work for Dynamic.ExpandoObject"? What is "this"; your own answer or do you refer to another answer?

Comment: I was referring to the code var newOrder = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x["Name"]);    when used in Dynamic.ExpandoObject.

Comment: You mean WooHoo's answer from above?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it wasn't working, for Dynamic.ExpandoObject but for ExpandoObject alone its working.